# Почему у меня double не правильно выводится?

Tags: c, ieee-754

Скажите пожалуйста где у меня ошибка, почему у меня не получается вывести(полностью) число double формата в двоичном формате?

> Вот напримере 20.18

```
0 10000000011 0100001011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110
```

> Количество бит соответствует стандарту [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format), первый бит
>   (знак) соответствует началу это точно, потому-что я пробовал -20.18,
>   там 1 получается, а вот остальное вообще не сходится :(

---

Вот собственно сам код:

```
void PrintByte(char a) //выводит на экран монитора двоичное представление переменной а типа unsigned char.
{
    int i;
    char mask = 1 << 7;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        printf("%i", a & mask ? 1 : 0);
        a <<= 1;
    }
}

void PrintVar(void *a, int size) //выводит на экран монитора двоичное представление переменной а произвольного типа размером size байт
{
    int i;
    char *p = a;
    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i--) PrintByte(*(p + i));
    puts("");
}

int main() {
    double d = 20.18;
    PrintVar(&d, sizeof(double));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Потому что little endian?

Comment: @andreymal так а почему int и unsigned char правильно выводится?

Comment: Хм, пришло время сходить проверить

Comment: Погуглил матчасть — да не, всё нормально у вас, первый бит знак, `10000000011` — смещённая на 1023 экспонента (0b10000000011 - 1023 = 4), остальное мантисса. По формуле считаем `(1+мантисса/2**52) * 2**(экспонента - 1023)` → `(1+0b0100001011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110/2**52) * 2**(0b10000000011 - 1023)` = `20.18` — всё верно (`**` это возведение в степень, считал в python)

Comment: @andreymal так а как исправить? ))

Comment: Ничего не нужно исправлять, с этим кодом всё в порядке и он всё выводит правильно. Я не сразу заметил, что он уже адаптирован под little endian)

Comment: @andreymal ну распишите с душой ответ, я проголосую )

Comment: С душой лень. .

Comment: @andreymal ну скопируйте свой коммент в ответ, я всё равно закрою тему, что ей висеть открытой)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, благодаря [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) я понял, что всё работает правильно, только я не смог догадаться что результат правильный но он высчитывается по следующей формуле:

```
Первый бит знак | 10000000011 — смещённая на 1023 экспонента (0b10000000011 - 1023 = 4) | остальное мантисса.
```

По формуле считаем (Python):

> `(1+мантисса/2**52) * 2**(экспонента - 1023) ->(1+0b0100001011100001010001111010111000010100011110101110/2**52) * 2**(0b10000000011 - 1023) = 20.18`