# "Безразмерный" double C++

Tags: c++, double, точность

Хотел поинтересоваться, писал свои матрицы, когда написал функцию возвращения детерминанта ради шутки решил вписать размеры `100x100`, `150x150` и увидел интересную картину, вместо случайных чисел он начал из раза в раз выдавать стабильные значения, большие `+e100` и в контрольных значениях указан. `sizeof` стабильно выдает 8 байт для `double`. Вот код, не знаю, поможет он чем-то:

```
int main(void)
{
    const int size = 150;
    Matrix m(size, size);
    m = Matrix(size, size);
    for (int i(0); i < size; i++)
        for (int j(0); j < size; j++)
            m[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    printf("Det: %lf, %d\n", m.Det(), sizeof(m.Det()));
}
```

Вот вывод:
`Det: -72307913218522825190636603121783109533943228668406806586004572432437176480990402652098139729226027559410013518523090670966620728946993881767856223758918815571231759806000656978596226673131379515981824.000000, 8`
Время не обнулял, но при одной сессии `Visual Studio` дает стабильно одно и тоже число

Comment: Само собой, double — 64 бита. Это в стандарте так: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Число_двойной_точности

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev Да это понятно, но что тогда это за значение

Comment: Вот тут полчаса назад например был вопрос и в нем код, выдающий число в двоичном виде, как оно в памяти лежит. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/882860/194569 вы свое число на нем прогоните и посмотрите по той статье в википедии, может найдете его там в примерах, может это -Infinity например ?

Comment: @Mike `-inf` выводит если я беру размер ну или что-то похожее 250x250

Comment: Поскольку вы не инициализируете генератор случайных чисел чем-то с помощью `srand()`, то при каждом запуске он выдает одну и ту же последовательность `rand()` - что, естественно, приводит к одной и той же матрице, и к вычислению одного и того же значения определителя... Вас же это волнует, нет?

Comment: @Harry Извиняюсь, за то что долго не отвечал. Нет немного не это. Я как раз для этого не прописывал `srand()`, чтобы всегда была одна и матрица, мне было интересно почему метод `Det()`, имеющий тип `double` имеет такое большое значение

Comment: А что вы хотите при таких размерах матрицы? На первый взгляд 100 на 100 и даст что-то типа 100 с какой-то там степенью...

Comment: @Harry Нет я просто говорю то что такое число большое хранится в `double`, где всего 8 байт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наконец выяснилось, в чем проблема :)

Просто *точных* знаков там наберется штук 15, только и всего. Это - **не точное** значение, просто вы попросили его вывести так - вот компилятор и рад стараться.

Вот простенький код:

```
double f = 1.0;
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) f*=i;
printf("%lf\n",f);
```

Вот как выглядит 100! при таком вычислении и его **точное** значение - сами посчитайте, сколько цифр совпадает... Я там пробельчики добавил :)

```
933262154439441 02188325606108575267240944254854960571509166910400407995064242937148632694030450512898042989296944474898258737204311236641477561877016501813248.000000
933262154439441 52681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000
```

Весь вопрос в том, как правильно трактовать то, что вы видите на экране...